# Python Pillow library does not visible to localhost

Tags: javascript, php, python-2.7, python-imaging-library

Python Pillow is available in my local environment(python2.7), but when I try to run python script using PHP, inside localhost, following error is returning,
but I could use other libraries without a issue this way and also Python Pillow work without issue locally.

Can anyone please help

**ajex** (request)

```
 $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: 'http:/localhost/simulator/data.php',
              dataType: "json",
                     success: function(out)
                     {
                      print("sucess!");
                      print(out);
                     }

    });
```

**php** (data.php)

```
<?php

$result =  shell_exec('python ./index.py 2>&1 ');
echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

**python** (index.py)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys,os,json,cv2,pickle
import PIL
from PIL import Image

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("got")
```

**Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./import.py", line 3, in <module>
    import PIL
ImportError: No module named PIL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess there might be an issue with where and how PIL is installed in your filesystem. For instance, PIL can be only installed for user A and your script is being executed by another user. Let's say you run Nginx for a web server. Then your **data.php** shell_exec runs from nginx user, where PIL might be installed only for your localhost user. (Assuming You are using Linux)

Moreover, try using [Pillow](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/) instead:

```
pip install Pillow
```

It is currently maintained fork of PIL (Latest release 1 Oct 2018). For my knowledge, PIL is no longer being developed.

Comment: you are correct apparently pillow is not visible to the  www-data  in my env